# How to transfer iTunes from Windows to Mac wirelessly?

Tags: windows, macos, itunes

Is there a way to transfer the content of my iTunes library from a Windows laptop to a MacBook over our house's network?

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4527 The home sharing option is best if you have an Apple id and store account.

Answer (score 0):

You could get PuTTY and ssh into your Mac and if that works just do scp -r of the iTunes Media folder. That would get you started. You will have to rebuild your library after that...